# Firefox не кэширует Google Fonts

Tags: шрифты, firefox, кэширование

Собственно суть проблемы проста. Шрифты подключены через

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,300i,400,400i&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
```

В хроме один раз прогрузились и всё прекрасно. В лисе при каждом обновлении страницы она сначала опрашивает 4 раза гугл, выкачивая шрифты заново и только затем обновляет страницу.

Comment: Может в инструментах разработчика FireFox отмечена опция «Не использовать кэш»?

Comment: Firefox был установлен специально для тестирования вёрстки и не настраивался вообще. Не думаю, что эта функция включена по-умолчанию.

Comment: Как раз по умолчанию и включена.